# How to change the repository settings for yum installer?

Tags: software-installation, yum, repository

I am pretty much new to Linux. I am trying to install tint2 on CentOS. When I try to install using the command `yum install tint2`, it gave following error

```
checking for X11... configure: error: Package requirements (x11 xcomposite xdamage xinerama xrender xrandr) were not met:

No package 'xcomposite' found
No package 'xdamage' found
No package 'xinerama' found
No package 'xrandr' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables X11_CFLAGS
and X11_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.`
```

When I try to install those packages which I belive should be done using

```
$>yum install xinerama
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
 * extras: mirror.rackspace.com
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
Setting up Install Process
No package xinerama available.
Nothing to do
```

I am bit unclear here. How can I change the yum settings to look for x* packages at the different  repository where packages are available?

What does it mean when it says

```
"Alternatively, you may set the environment variables X11_CFLAGS
and X11_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
```

Comment: do you have X11 installed? you can try `yum search X11`. that will give you all the packages that mention X11 in their description (its probably going to be a lot consider piping the output to `less`)

Answer (score 0):

You can set Yum to phrase alternative repo's by downloading & installing the .rpm file of the repo. Proper instructions can be found in [EPEL repo installation](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x)

Answer (score 0):

Search for other repository which includes `xinerama`.
Download and Install that repository with `rpm new`. The repo will be created in `/etc/yum.repos.d`

and run `yum install xinerama`